# Customizing chapter style with tikz - Vertical rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, chapters

I've seen multiple examples of chapter styling using TikZ, but they all use horizontal rectangles and/or lines to customize chapter page, but is it possible to do a vertical one like the one on the picture below? Does anyone kow how to do it? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there is a package for it somewhere (`wallpaper` comes to mind) but you can hack it with `tikz`'s page reference functionality (pgf manual, section 17.13).

Comment: Probably just a matter of changing the coordinates, can you show an example with a horizontal rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my mind about a couple of things, but this is the final result I've got:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twosides]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[top color=green, bottom color=blue] 
(16,-23) rectangle (18.5,7);
\node[
    anchor= east,
    xshift=1cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.east) {\fontsize{30}{36}\sffamily\selectfont#1};
\node[
    anchor= east,
    inner xsep=3cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{blue}]%,
    at ([yshift=.5cm]current page.east|-titlerect.east)
     {\fontsize{80}{86}\bfseries\thechapter};
\node[
    anchor= east,
    xshift=11.5cm,
        yshift=-11cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.east) {\fontsize{30}{36}\scshape\selectfont\rotatebox{90}{\color{white}#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[top color=green, bottom color=blue] 
    (16,-25) rectangle (18.5,7);
  \node[
   anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=6cm,
        yshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
   at (titlerect.south west) {\sffamily\Huge#1};
    \node[
    anchor= east,
    xshift=11.5cm,
        yshift=-11cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.east) {\fontsize{30}{36}\scshape\selectfont\rotatebox{90}{\color{white}#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }[]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}
\titleformat{\section}[display] 
{\bfseries\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{\color{blue}\thesection~~ #1}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[display]
{\bfseries\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
{\itshape\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{\color{blue}\thesection~~ #1}

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm}
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\textwidth=13cm
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Random}

\section{Lipsum}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I know it is not the prettiest solution, and there are probably much simpler ways to do it, but at least it got the job done! Hopefully it can help someone.

Comment: Your code is not compilable. There is this error: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named `titlerect' is known`. Can you look at a question about it here? [could some one fix tikz code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560166/138900)