# Could some one fix this tikz code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

```
\documentclass[11pt, twosides]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[top color=green, bottom color=blue] 
(16,-23) rectangle (18.5,7);
\node[
    anchor= east,
    xshift=1cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.east) {\fontsize{30}{36}\sffamily\selectfont#1};
\node[
    anchor= east,
    inner xsep=3cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{blue}]%,
    at ([yshift=.5cm]current page.east|-titlerect.east)
     {\fontsize{80}{86}\bfseries\thechapter};
\node[
    anchor= east,
    xshift=11.5cm,
        yshift=-11cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.east) {\fontsize{30}{36}\scshape\selectfont\rotatebox{90}{\color{white}#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[top color=green, bottom color=blue] 
    (16,-25) rectangle (18.5,7);
  \node[
   anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=6cm,
        yshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
   at (titlerect.south west) {\sffamily\Huge#1};
    \node[
    anchor= east,
    xshift=11.5cm,
        yshift=-11cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.east) {\fontsize{30}{36}\scshape\selectfont\rotatebox{90}{\color{white}#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }[]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}
\titleformat{\section}[display] 
{\bfseries\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{\color{blue}\thesection~~ #1}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[display]
{\bfseries\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
{\itshape\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{\color{blue}\thesection~~ #1}

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm}
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\textwidth=13cm
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Random}

\section{Lipsum}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the MWE from the question seems to be similar (identical?) to the code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374634/134144).

Comment: @leandriis . yes, this code from answer on question Customizing chapter style with tikz - Vertical rectangle. but I can't add comment , because my reputation.

Comment: I left a [comment for you there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373999/customizing-chapter-style-with-tikz-vertical-rectangle/374634#comment1412808_374634)

Comment: @AndréC . thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the node `titlerec` is supposed to be the rectangle created with the initial `\fill` command. We can replace this with a node by using the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `fit` library and the page nodes from [tikzpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) to fix the problem.

The code below now compiles without errors to give the desired output. Of course, initially, the hard work was done in the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374634/134144. This said, I have rationalised the code, made better use of [tikzpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes), made the numbered and numberless versions consistent and taken out some code that I thought unnecessary. Once this is done the code produces:

[image]

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twosides]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (SE) at ([xshift=-50]current page.south east);
    \node[top color=green, bottom color=blue, 
        fit=(current page.north east)(SE)](titlerect){};
    \node[font=\fontsize{30}{36}\sffamily\selectfont] 
        at (current page text area.north){#1};
    \node[xshift=-25, font=\fontsize{80}{86}\bfseries\color{blue}]
        at (current page text area.north east-|titlerect.west)
        {\thechapter};
    \node[xshift=25, 
          font=\fontsize{30}{36}\scshape\selectfont\color{white}]
       at (current page.center-|titlerect.west) {\rotatebox{90}{#1}};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[top color=green, bottom color=blue, 
        fit=(current page.north east)(SE)](titlerect){};
    \node[font=\fontsize{30}{36}\sffamily\selectfont] 
       at (current page text area.north){#1};
    \node[xshift=25, 
       font=\fontsize{30}{36}\scshape\selectfont\color{white}]
       at (current page.center-|titlerect.west) {\rotatebox{90}{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\bfseries\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{\color{blue}\thesection~~ #1}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[display]
{\bfseries\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
{\itshape\normalsize}
{}
{5pt}
{\color{blue}\thesection~~ #1}

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm}
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Random}

\section{Lipsum}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Random}

\section{Lipsum}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```